# Finding certain words in a paragraph class with each line in an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, search, find

I have been trying to make a simple menu where the user can enter a line that they want to add to the paragraph and then search the word(s) that they enter.
However, in the case of searching the words (Case 3) if the word that they search is not in the first line it doesn't work (I get no errors) but my code works in a separate file with manual inputs.

Here is my class

```
public class Paragraph {

String[] lines;
int lineCount;
public Paragraph(String[]lines,int lineCount) {
    this.lines = lines;
    this.lineCount = lineCount;
    
}   
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lineCount=0 , i = 0;
    String[] lines = new String[10];
    String curline ,search; 
    boolean loop= true; 

    Paragraph parag = new Paragraph(lines, lineCount);

    while(loop) {       
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%s\n","1) Enter a new line");
        System.out.printf("%s\n","2) Display the paragraph");           
        System.out.printf("%s\n","3) Search for word");
        System.out.printf("%s\n","4) Exit");
        int choice= myScanner.nextInt();

        myScanner.nextLine();
        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter your line:");
            curline = myScanner.nextLine();
            lineCount = i;
            System.out.println("Done!!");
            parag.lines[i] =  curline + " ";
            parag.lineCount = i;
            i++;
            break;
        case 2:
            int index;
            for(index=0;  index<i; index++) {
                System.out.printf("(%d) %s\n",index+1, lines[index]);
                }   
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Enter pharese to be searched:");
            search = myScanner.nextLine();
            String toBeSearched = search;
            String[] divide = toBeSearched.split(" ");
                
                for(int i1 = 0; i1 < divide.length ; i1 ++) {
                    String word = divide[i1];
                    for(int y = 0; y < lineCount; y++) {
                        if(lines[y].contains(word)) {
                            System.out.println(word + " found at line: "+ y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            break;
        case 4:
            loop = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the way that I take the lines in the Case 1 can cause the issue but here is my other file that I tested the Case 3  which doesn't work here

Here is my separate file which I tested Case 3

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        String toBeSearched;
        boolean intIndex = false ;
        String paragraph[] = {"Hello my name is","Jack the reaper", "what up"};
        System.out.printf("enter string:");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        toBeSearched = myScanner.nextLine();
       
    String[] divide = toBeSearched.split(" ");
   
    for(int i = 0; i < divide.length ; i ++) {
        String word = divide[i];
        for(int y = 0; y < paragraph.length ; y++) {
            if(paragraph[y].contains(word)) {
                System.out.println(word + " found at line: "+ y);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here when I search for "Hello Jack" it gives me

Hello found at line 0
Jack  found at line 1

But in my class above it doesnt work any ideas?

Comment: @Typhon it can be multiple words as well just one lets say line 1 is "Hello my name is" and line 2 is "Jack Rock" if the user inputs "Hello Jack" I want it to output Hello is found at  line 1 and Jack found at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j <3 ; j++) {
   paragraph[j] ="Hello my name is" ;
}
```

This piece of code, changes your `paragraph`. Therefore, you are searching for `"Hello Jack"` in

```
{ "Hello my name is",
  "Hello my name is",
  "Hello my name is" }
```

Please delete the for loop and try again.

Edit: Your program works fine for the input you gave on my computer, can't reproduce the error. Make sure you compile/run the correct code.

[image]

Edit 2: You have an indexing problem. See the code below;

```
// When you enter the first line...
case 1:
    System.out.println("Enter your line:");
    curline = myScanner.nextLine();
    lineCount = i; // i is 0, but we have 1 line
    System.out.println("Done!!");
    parag.lines[i] = curline + " "; // parag[0] is set, correct
    parag.lineCount = i; // i is 0, but we have 1 line
    i++;
    break;
```

Should be:

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("Enter your line:");
    curline = myScanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Done!!");
    parag.lines[i] = curline + " "; // parag[0] is set, correct
    i++;
    parag.lineCount = i; // i is 1, correct
    lineCount = i; // i is 1, correct
    break;
```

Comment: Oh that was in a comment sorry that is not part of the code . The second code works the first one doesn't

Comment: Üstteki bir Paragraph classında case 3  bir türlü çalışmıyor.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Im using eclipse with Java 15

Comment: I have JDK 15 with Eclipse compiler, too.

Comment: I tried to run it on outside the İde but i dont get the same outputs as you do

Comment: Sadece hello my name ile Jack the reaper ı girince çalışmıyor kod sanırım. Paragraf 2 satırdan oluşunca düzgün çalışmıyor. 3 Satır girip denedim şimdi doğru basıyor ancak  10 kere aynı outputu basıyor. Mesela yazdığınız satırları girip "what" kelimesini ararsanız hiçbir şey basmıyor

Comment: Acaba what kelimesini girip deneyebilir misiniz ? Bende çalışmıyor onu girdiğimde

Comment: Çok çok çok aşırı teşekkür ederim bu düzgün basıyor benim sistemimde ancak galiba looptaki bir hatadan dolayı aradığım şeyi girdiğimde düzgün ancak birkaç kez basıyor. Sizde de öyle bir şey oluyor mu yoksa 1 kez basıp bitiyor mu

Comment: Prints out only once. Might be a bug from eclipse. Try running on CMD. If the answer helped you please mark it as accepted.